# IIS 10 Rewrite 301

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-301, iis-10

I really need help,

I can't figure out how to make a 301 redirection on IIS 10 Windows Server 2016.
I need to redirect
from
https://hostname/**folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4**/xxxxx_1.jpg
to
https://hostname/**folder6/folder7/folder8/folder9/folder10**/xxxxx_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IIS Rewrite Module for that

```
<rule name="RewriteFolder" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/folder6/folder7/folder8/folder9/folder10/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```